# Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\N_A_M_E\anaconda3\python.exe

Tags: python, conda

I can't activate my conda environment

I tried to Install Tensorflow Object Detection
and this error happened,
I can't use my conda environments

it says

"Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\Mark Vincent\anaconda3\python.exe "C:\Users\Mark Vincent\anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py" shell.cmd.exe activate "C:\Users\Mark Vincent\anaconda3\envs\DeepSSD" '"

[terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciKBa.png)

Comment: It could be that conda is failing because you have a space in your user name.
You could try to create a symlink to your username that contains no spaces
`mklink /D C:\Users\mark_vincent "C:\Users\Mark Vincent"`
Then you need to point conda to this new username

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.